# Tags with hyphens don't autocomplete

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, tags

I was creating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41651416/328397) and wanted the tag for OData-v4, however, the only tag listed as suggested tags was OData.

Tags that have a hyphen seem to have problems appearing in the autocomplete list.

Comment: Looks like the tag editor ignores hyphens when auto-completing. If I type "odata" then one of the matches is "django-database", and if I type "odatav" then "odata-v4" shows up.